# BigQuery - add description to set of schemas

Tags: google-bigquery

In my work came into a set of tables which all have the same schema. Until now no one made descriptions to the columns in the table and I want to add my description to them. My question is how to add my schema's descriptions to all the tables (about hundreds of them) without going every table and change it manualy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using bq command line tool, you can prepare a quick script on Linux.
Firstly, list all the tables by using "bq show" command, secondly in a loop put the needed descriptions to the tables by using "bq update" command.

Just for further help, here a link explaining how to write shell scripts:
http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Shell-Script-Using-Bash-Shell-in-Ubuntu

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the website by using a query? Or only via the command line?

Comment: Apart from "bq command line tool", if you are already using one of the [BigQuery APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries), you can also write a small application by using it. But in my opinion, just for "description" updates using "bq command line tool" will be easier than using the API.